# how can I show that $a^n\rightarrow 0$ if $0<a<1$

Tags: analysis

It is clear for the high school students,
but I must use the 'elementary analysis' way to prove the statement.

I tried to show it by assuming the contrary, but it didn't give me a good result.

Comment: Are you looking for a $\varepsilon$-$N$ proof?

Comment: Are you familiar with the theorem about bounded monotonous sequences converging?

Comment: yeah, all of them are familiar to me.

Comment: epsilon-delta is the only way that I can utilize.

Comment: ?? Compare "high school students" and "elementary analysis" with "epsilon-delta is the only way that I can utilize".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a^n$ is less than $1$, positive and decreasing, so must have some limit $L<1$. Suppose $L>0$. Then $L^2<L$, so we have some $1>\epsilon>0$ such that $L^2<L-\epsilon$. Let $n$ be such that $a^n-L<\epsilon/3$. Then $a^{n}<L+\epsilon/3$, so 
$$a^{2n}<L^2+2L\epsilon/3+\epsilon^2/9<L-\epsilon + 2\epsilon/3 + \epsilon/9 < L$$
contradicting the fact that $a^n>L$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you do not want to use this

> Bounded and strictly decreasing, hence limit $l$ exists and $al=l$ must hold.

So you need to show: For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|a^n|<\epsilon$.
As $a<1$, there is $m\in \mathbb N$ with $a<1-\frac 1{m+1}$. Then (as $a>0$) 
$$0< a^n<\left(1-\frac1{m+1}\right)^n=\frac1{\left(1+\frac1m\right)^n}$$
From Bernoulli, $$\left(1+\frac1m\right)^n>1+\frac nm\to\infty .$$
In other words, as soon as $$n>\frac m\epsilon-m$$
we have $0<a^n<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

For every $x\geqslant0$ and $n\geqslant1$, $$(1+x)^n\geqslant1+nx.$$ If you are allowed to use this, rewrite $a^n$ as $1/(1+x)^n$ with $x=(1-a)/a$. This yields
$$
a^n
\leqslant
\frac1{1+nx}
=
\frac{a}{a+n(1-a)}
\leqslant
\frac{a}{1-a}\,\frac1n
\to0.
$$